# Align two divs in another div, without one going on the bottom and using relative sizes

Tags: html, css

I know all this can seem pretty difficult and has been asked many times before, but the cases I found just don't work. Now, I basically want to do something like that

```
| Element | Content                                |
| Element | Content two                            |
| Element | random                                 |
| Element | Content lorem                          |
| Element | Content ipsum and I don't know what to |
| Element | Content write                          |
| Element | Content                                |
```

So basically the user selects an item from the left (it's not a select, it's stacked links), and on the right he can see the content of what he selected. Though, I want that the whole thing makes 80% of the page, and the thing on the left 20%, and the thing on the right 80%. But, if I put widthes to 20% and 80% (so that makes in total 100% of the parent div). Though, it puts the content div at the bottom (he probably wants to draw something it doesn't have place for so...). 
Would you have any idea of how I can resolve that ? I'm starting to lose hair.

Thank you in advance

Comment: add the code you have tried, that way it's a lot easier to help you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of implementing this requires HTML, CSS, and JavaScript ( to update the righthand side content ).

Create 2 divs, float them side by side. Attach `onclick` events to all of your links that call a function which gets the right hand sie content by ID and changes its `innerHTML` to whatever you want.

```js
function clicked( element ){
  if( element.id == "one" ){
      document.getElementById( 'right' ).innerHTML = 'You clicked link <b>1</b>';
  }
  else if( element.id == "two" ){
      document.getElementById( 'right' ).innerHTML = 'You clicked the <b>second</b> link';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById( 'right' ).innerHTML = 'Link <b>3</b> was your choice.';
  }
}
```

```css
html, body{
  margin:0; padding:0;
  height:100%; width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  }

#left{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background:#ddd;
    height:100%;
  }

#right{
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    background:#eee;
    height:100%;
  }

b{ font-size:150%; }
```

```html
<div id ="left">
  <a href="#" id="one" onclick="clicked( this )">Link 1</a><br>
  <a href="#" id="two" onclick="clicked( this )">Link 2</a><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="clicked( this )">Link 3</a><br>
</div>
<div id="right">
  Content
</div>
```

Comment: It works great, but actually I didn't want to use float... :/

Comment: Why didn't you want to use float?

Comment: Because I always find people on Internet or IRL saying "float is deprecated don't use float float is evil it will bring the world to its end."

Comment: Are you serious? I don't mean to sound rude but those people are clueless. Float is an essential CSS property that is used on virtually all major websites including this one. View source to see for yourself. Also it is not even close to being deprecated.

Comment: And actually, it doesn't work in my example :/ I can't get the right thing to be full size of the parent (margin: auto doesn't work) and I noticed using 20% was actually dumb, so I'm using a static 273px. But how can I do then to have the right thing dynamically set ? 
PS : the whole thing is here (for the tests) : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoVeRG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74385/discussion-between-lynel-hudson-and-thomas-pat-kowalski-zuckerberg).

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier. I accepted but I don't know at all this system.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried bootstrap? You could do it with

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
</div>

<div class="col-d-2">
</div>
```